# From the middle of a large MS Word 2007 doc, I would like to select text to top of doc

Tags: text-editors

I want to delete about 100 pages from a MS Word document.  From the middle, I would like to select text from there all the way to the top of the document, so I can delete half the document without hitting the page up key repeatedly.

Answer (score 9):

Try <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>home</kbd> that should work

Comment: IT WORKS!!!   IT WORKS!!!  You have saved me from getting grey hair!